# Javascript code not running properly

Tags: javascript, html, image, onmouseover, onmouseout

i just finished my code but instead of showing tick.gif it shows the word "tick" with a box over it. Also the onmouseover feature isn't working either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Changeup test</title>
</head>
<body>
<img scr="tick.gif" alt="tick" onmouseover="this.scr='tick2.gif';
"onmouseout="this.gif='tick.gif';" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fun fact... you don't need `this` to refer to the element's properties in a handler attribute. You can treat the properties like variables. `onmouseover="src='tick2.gif';"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source attribute for the  tag is misspelled in the code you pasted above. It needs to be src.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Changeup test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="tick.gif" alt="tick" onmouseover="this.src='tick2.gif'; "onmouseout="this.src='tick.gif';" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.gif` should probably be `this.src` as well.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for not seeing that the first time. There is no property `.gif`. You should use `.src` instead. Thanks for spotting it.